# Directional After Effects Wiggle?

Tags: animation, graphics, expression, adobe, after-effects

I'm wondering if anyone can direct me to an After Effects wiggle expression that will control the wiggle so that it only wiggles in the y direction, AND only wiggles upwards, like it's wiggling against a floor? I'm trying to animate a hatching egg that seems to randomly jump up a bit.

I'm new to After Effects and not sure how to write the code that's required. All other resources that I've found online have been for a standard wiggle effect that doesn't fit my needs.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you're looking for a clamped wiggle. Check out the wiggles variations post in our expressions library: https://reelsmart.co/expression-library/wiggle/